# pthread_join causes termination on accept()

Tags: join, pthreads

I have an attached server thread blocked on an accept() waiting for connections.  Externally I try to terminate the thread by calling pthread_cancel(), followed by pthread_join().  Upon calling the join, my program terminates with a SIGABRT.

I am, more than likely going to the detach the thread, and make it select() with a timeout to check for connections, so I can then "signal" it to quit.  So, I know this is a solution, but being the curious type, I was wondering why the first solution doesn't work.

Comment: I'm interested in finding out too. Have you tried  to `pthread_setcancelstate()` before the `pthread_cancel()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting the program termination SIGABRT because of the pthread_cancel() -- when the blocked thread gets the signal, it probably dies.  The signal delivery doesn't happen until after the call to pthread_cancel() has returned, so it just looks like it occurs because of the join call.

To check and see if my thoughts are right, I would insert a while(1); loop after the pthread_cancel() to see if you still get the SIGABRT.